# What does systemctl with status command?

Tags: systemd

When I run eg:

`systemctl status nut-monitor.service`

what does systemd do?

If I take a look to unit file I don't find any clue:

```
 cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nut-monitor.service
[Unit]
Description=Network UPS Tools - power device monitor and shutdown controller
After=local-fs.target network.target nut-server.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create /etc/tmpfiles.d/nut-run.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/upsmon -F
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache and systemctl status](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290923/apache-and-systemctl-status)

Answer (score 3):

From `man systemctl`

```
Show terse runtime status information about one or more units, followed by most recent log data from the journal.
           If no units are specified, show system status. If combined with --all, also show the status of all units (subject
           to limitations specified with -t). If a PID is passed, show information about the unit the process belongs to.

           This function is intended to generate human-readable output. If you are looking for computer-parsable output, use
           show instead. By default this function only shows 10 lines of output and ellipsizes lines to fit in the terminal
           window. This can be changes with --lines and --full, see above. In addition, journalctl --unit=NAME use a similar
           filter for messages and might be more convenient.
```

Basically `systemctl status` will show if the service is running, if it is enabled, and it will show last 10 lines from systemd logs.

You can get the same log output by doing `journalctl --unit=servicename | tail -10` like for example `journalctl --unit=sshd | tail -10`